# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 12000 y sizes: 640 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**I tried to train the dataset with tensorflow but i got error on Data cardinality.**

> ***code**

```
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

def read_patches(Image_path, label):
    patches = []
    labels = []
    Image_File_name = []

    for (path,dir,files) in os.walk(Image_path):
        files.sort()
        for filename in files :
            if('good' in filename):
                Image_File_name.append(Image_path+'\\'+filename)


    for i in range(len(Image_File_name)):
        # print(Image_File_name[i])
        patch = cv2.imread(Image_File_name[i])
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(patch, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #RGB to Gray

        patches.append(gray)
        labels.append(label)

    patches = np.array(patches)
    labels = np.array(labels)

    patchDim = patches.shape
    patches = np.reshape(patches, (patchDim[0], patchDim[1], patchDim[2], 1) )
    labels = np.reshape(labels, (len(labels), 1) )

    return patches, labels

X, Y = read_patches("C:\\works\\data\\image_source_01\\good", 1) 

train_X = train_X.reshape(-1, 32, 32, 1)
test_X = test_X.reshape(-1, 32, 32, 1)
print(train_X.shape, test_X.shape)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape=(32,32,1), kernel_size=(3, 3), filters = 32, 
padding='same', activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters = 64, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(strides=(2, 2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters = 128, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters = 256, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(strides=(2, 2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')                        
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
          
model.summary()

history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=25, validation_split=0.25)
```

> ***error**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\works\test4.py", line 139, in 
history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=25, validation_split=0.25)
...
packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1649, in _check_data_cardinality
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 12000
y sizes: 640
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says it all: you need to make sure `train_X` and `train_Y` have the same shape. If you load your mnist data like this, you will notice that `x_train` has the shape `(60000, 28, 28, 1)` and `y_train` the shape (60000,):

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

Notice that both have 60000 samples. Your `train_X` has 12000 images and `train_Y` has 640 labels and that won't work, since every image needs a corresponding label. Furthermore, I do not think you have to reshape your data, but it depends how it looks before that.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. But when I run the code,
I could see these results below

Comment: *print(train_X.shape, train_Y.shape)
: (16000, 32, 32, 1) (640, 1) 
*print(test_X.shape, test_Y.shape)
: (4000, 32, 32, 1) (160, 1)

Comment: So at the moment, I cannot find where the number 12000 is from. Plus, both train_X and train_Y wouldn’t be the same shape as  train_X data is image and train_Y data is label

Comment: So… you’re saying that as the number of each data should be the same? I mean train_X are 16000 images and train_y have 640 labels, so should they be like the same number of data? Like 640 images and 640 labels?

Comment: Exactly, you understood it right. I am talking about the number of samples which have to be the same. Maybe just use the dataset provided by tensorflow: `tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()`. That way you won`t have any problems.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could I ask you again if i have any problem that I can’t figure out?

Comment: I appreciate very much for your replies..

I’ve just found out that I put the wrong words in the title. It’s not ‘mnist dataset’ but an assignment. So i won’t be able to use the tensorflow dataset you mentioned… 
Will there be any solution for this matter? 
 Thank you again

Comment: I need to know what your dataset looks like and how you want to use it

Comment: I added it to the text. Can you check it out?

Comment: What shapes do X and Y have before you reshape them?

Comment: Yeah, what is the output of the print statements?

Comment: print(train_X.shape)
--->(640, 160, 160, 1)

Comment: print(test_X.shape)
--->(160, 160, 160, 1)

Comment: print(train_Y.shape)
---->(640, 1)

Comment: print(test_Y.shape)
---->(160, 1)

Comment: When I run the code, the result value comes out like this.

Comment: Ok, remove these lines from your code and run it again: `train_X = train_X.reshape(-1, 32, 32, 1)` and `test_X = test_X.reshape(-1, 32, 32, 1)`