# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 3070 y sizes: 6140 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

can you help me please. When I try to check my result on a test samples. I have an error.

```
score = saved_model_bilstm.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print ("Test Loss:%.2f%%" % (score[0]))
print ("Acurracy:%.2f%%" % (score[1]))
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: what line does the value error say that it's coming from?

Comment: ValueError 
----> 1 score = saved_model_bilstm.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
      2 print ("Test Loss:%.2f%%" % (score[0]))
      3 print ("Acurracy:%.2f%%" % (score[1]))

1 frames
python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1655     for i in tf.nest.flatten(single_data)))
   1656     msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1657     raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 3070
  y sizes: 6140
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69611834/valueerror-data-cardinality-is-ambiguous-x-sizes-12000-y-sizes-640-make-sure

Comment: I've tried that, but it gets an error when I want to make the model. ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_3" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "bidirectional_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (128, 28, 28, 32)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(128, 28, 28), dtype=uint8)
      • training=True
      • mask=None.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.